# Tensorflow import error

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda

I'm trying to install tensorflow which supports GPU.

I tried the information in the following link

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

1. CUDA® Toolkit 8.0
2. cuDNN v6.0
3. GPU card with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 - GeForce 940MX

Then used `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` to install tensorflow.

But I'm getting the following error when trying to import tensorflow.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
        ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
        import tensorflow as tf
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import *
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
        self_check.preload_check()
      File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
        % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
    ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

Can someone please advice me on how to use this.

Comment: As it mentions in the error message `Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit` and add the path to the directory having `cudart64_90.dll` to environment variable `PATH` in windows.

Comment: But the Requirements to run TensorFlow with GPU support, says to  install CUDA® Toolkit 8.0. For details, see NVIDIA's documentation Ensure that you append the relevant Cuda pathnames to the %PATH% environment variable as described in the NVIDIA documentation

Comment: It may be that the latest version of tensorflow-gpu requires CUDA 9 but the documentation has not been updated to reflect this. You may be able to install an earlier version of tensorflow using e.g. pip install --upgrade "tensorflow-gpu==1.4". You might try replacing 1.4 with 1.3 or 1.2 if you encounter the same issue.

Comment: Thanks .. When version 1.3 is installed the error didn't throw.. :)

Comment: Make sure you activate the environment in which you've installed these things :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and had to be very careful about the version of CUDA, and the version of CuDNN. I hit the exact error you are hitting, and fixed it by going through what I documented here: http://www.laurencemoroney.com/installing-tensorflow-with-gpu-on-windows-10/

Give it a try! :)

(The most common failure I've found is that you download the *latest* CUDA, and not the *matching* CUDA. Right now CUDA is at 9.1, but TF requires 9.0 -- your error says cudart90.dll) -- so find the 9.0 drivers, download and install them. Then run TensorFlow. It might then fail on the CuDNN drivers, which is good, becuase you know CUDA is right. Then download the right CuDNN drivers (matching the version # in the error) and try again.)

Comment: well I have correct versions, I have those dll, but I still get this error, details: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/issues/57

Comment: Weird...I noticed that your issue is with the 64 bit version of cudart90 -- I'm wondering if there's something different there.

Are you sure you uninstalled all CUDA post 9.0, then rebooted, then installed 9.0?

Comment: Yes, I have only Cuda 9.0  in "program files", "environment variables" and in "app and features"

Comment: Thank you very much.  This was exactly what I needed to align the versions and get the tensorflow module imported to python.

Answer (score 1):

Please download the proper drivers as latest version of cuda v8.0 toolkit needs tensorflow 1.4.x needs.

As, by default `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` install latest version of tensorflow which needs cuda v9.0 (latest) not cuda v8.0 toolkit

You'll need to install the version 1.4.1 for CUDA-8 as

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1
```

The latest (version 1.5) is for CUDA-9
You'll need to install the version 1.5 for CUDA-9 as

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.5
```

Download cuddn for your appropriate cuda version toolkit from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)
and follow [this](http://www.laurencemoroney.com/installing-tensorflow-with-gpu-on-windows-10/).

Download appropriate cuda toolkit from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive)