# Tensorflow Installation with CUDA 9.1 and Python 3.6 on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, windows-10, anaconda

I encountered this error installing TensorFlow. Edit: I installed CUDA 9.0, and changed my environment variables including the Path variable, and now it works.

```
    (tensorflow-gpu) C:\Users\Admin>python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar  9 2018, 07:43:39) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
    % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

It is a very similar problem to this one.

[Tensorflow installation with CUDA 9.1 and python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311685/tensorflow-installation-with-cuda-9-1-and-python-3-6)

Comment: Your tensorflow build is expecting CUDA 9.0. `Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'` If you have installed CUDA 9.1 as stated in your question title, that will not work as a replacement.  You must use CUDA 9.0.

Comment: Why does it expect 9.0?

Comment: @gm9089zo: because that is what it was compiled against and has binary dependencies on

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to [Tensorflow import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477909/tensorflow-import-error/48478822#48478822)

The quick answer: By default NVidia will install the *latest* version of CUDA, which right now is 9.1

TensorFlow is expecting 9.0 as shown in the "ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'" -- Read this as cuda-runtime-64-bit-version9.0 DLL

To solve, go to the NVidia site to download the 9.0 version of the drivers and you'll be good to go. I wrote a guide here: http://www.laurencemoroney.com/installing-tensorflow-with-gpu-on-windows-10/